# Getting all tabs name with Google App Script and custom function of Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

## Goal:

I want to build a custom function in Google Sheet that can auto-generate all sheets name from another Google Sheets (with the filename of "2020-01" and it has multiple tabs inside, like "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03" and so on). 

With this custom function, I hope I can use the query formula to get the data from the multiple tabs in  "2020-01". Here is the code in Google App Script:

## Code:

```
function getsheetnames() {
  var out=[];
  var ss;
  var sheets;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++) {
    var sh=sheets[i];
    var name=sh.getName();
    out.push("'" + name + "'!$A:$O"); 
  }
  return '{' + out.join(';') + '}';
}
```

## Problem:

By now, I only get the following error message when I typed the formula =getsheetnames() in the cell, even I had already set the oauthScopes in appscript.json:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    ]
}
```

Hence, may I know what wrong with my code and how can I solve the problem of permission? Thank you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: Go to that link scroll down and you will see yourself that `openById` can not be used via a custom function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error msg from custom function when trying to open another spreadsheet. "You do not have permission to perform that action."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465600/error-msg-from-custom-function-when-trying-to-open-another-spreadsheet-you-do)

Comment: As the workaround for using `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` with the custom function, are these information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63553532 and https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper